# Ubuntu doesn't see my tablet

Tags: drivers, tablet, devices

I have ainol novo 10 quard tablet. When I connect it to Ubuntu by USB, it doesn't see it at all. Do I need to install ainol drivers? Or something else?

Comment: I'm sorry? 'Connect' it? Remote Desktop it? You need to explain the question more.

Comment: This is likely an **MTP** issue.  *Please add better detail.* Brand, model, connect by USB, etc.